# optimise simple mysql query with order by on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, query-optimization

I've only just began to run explain on my queries and see that the type is All and I'm using filesort.

I'm not sure how to optimise even the simplest of queries, if anyone could provide guidance on the following query which just retrieves users and orders by their first name primarily and second name secondarily:

```
SELECT UserID, TRIM(FName) AS FName, TRIM(SName) as SName, pic
FROM users WHERE Blocked <> 1
ORDER BY FName, SName 
LIMIT  ?, 10
```

Table is created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `SName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Pword` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `Latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `DateJoined` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `NotificationID` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `Pic` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Radius` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ads` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `Blocked` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1469 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Explain gives the following:

```
id : 1
select_type : SIMPLE
table : users 
type : ALL
possible_keys : NULL
key  : NULL
key_len : NULL
ref : NULL
rows : 1141
Extra : Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: It would be more optimized to use TRIM() on the INSERT rather than on the SELECT. So it's just called once and not each time.

Comment: perhaps the following index would help `alter table users add index block_fname_sname_idx(Blocked,FName,SName)`

Comment: @ôkio thanks will update that part!

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty thanks, I tried that but it didn't make a difference to the results of the explain

Comment: You seem to be doing "pagination via OFFSET".  This has problems, see [_my blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add index (Blocked, FName, SName)
And change where to `Blocked = 0`, if it is possible

Comment: This together with changing my TRIM to happen on insert gives me the optimisation I need. Thanks everyone for the answers, between everyone i understand it better now

Answer (score 1):

If you want optimize this query you could  create an index on the field in where condition

```
CREATE INDEX id_users_blocked ON users (Blocked) ;
```

the optimization depend by the number of users withBlocked <> 1

If these are few don't aspect particolar improvement .. but in explain you don't shoudl see All.

You can also add fname, sname in index field but the use of trim for a way and the need of the field pic can't make this index performant .. because if the firsta case the fields normally with function like trim are not get from index and in the second is not gooe an index with a field like pic .. so the access at the table row is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UserID, TRIM(FName) AS FName, TRIM(SName) as SName, pic
FROM users WHERE Blocked <> 1
ORDER BY FName, SName 
LIMIT  ?, 10
```

Let's analyze your query. You've used clause `WHERE` to extract values of column `Blocked` with `value <> 1`. Improving this clause depends on data distribution of values in the column `Blocked`. If only small part of data contains values

```
blocked <> 1
```

using `INDEX` on column `blocked` will give to you performance increase. In another case `INDEX` will not help to you.

You have also used `TRIM` function for each record of your table. If you removed it you will increase performance.

Off course, sort will also affect on query performance.